# Request Priority Queue in Node.js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, node.js, data-structures, asynchronous

I have an script that adds products to a remote database using a RESTful API in Node.js. It works well, but I would like to change the priority HTTP requests are processed. Here is some code to better illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
step(
    function initializeCategories() {
        createCategories(products, this);
    },
    function createProducts(err, categoriesHash) {
        console.log("\nCreating products:");
        console.log("==================");

        var group = this.group(),
            productDoneCallback;

        products.forEach(function (product) {
            product.categories = categoriesHash[product.category + "/" + product.make + "/" + product.model];
            productDoneCallback = group();

            step(
                function createProduct() {
                    postProduct(convertToBigCommerceObj(product), this);
                },
                function overwriteProduct(err, product, allowOverwrite) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                    allowOverwrite = allowOverwrite || false;

                    if (allowOverwrite) {
                        updateProduct(product, this);
                    } else {
                        this(err, product);
                    }
                },
                function addExtraInfo(err, product) {
                    addImage(product, productDoneCallback);
                }
            );
        });
    },
    function printStats(err) {
        if (err) {
            logError(err);
        }

        var endTime = +new Date(),
            duration = endTime - startTime;

        console.log("\nFinished after " + (duration / 1000 / 60) + " minutes");
        console.log(productsAdded + " Products added successfully");
        console.log(productsUpdated + " Products updated successfully");
        console.log(productsSkipped + " Products skipped");
        console.log("Average time (milliseconds) per product was : " + (duration / totalNumProducts ));
        console.log("For more information see error log (error.log)" );
    }
);
```

In this code the product images are always added last after all products have been added. This is because the forEach loop puts all of the postProduct requests on the node event queue right away. After the first product is done has been posted to the server another entry is added to the end of the queue to add that product's image. Instead, I would like that new entry to float to the top of the queue and be the next entry to be processed (not another product post, that can wait).

I realize that to do that I need a priority queue. I am just not sure how I can achieve this in Node and Javascript.

Update: after finding an implementation of a PriorityQueue at https://github.com/STRd6/PriorityQueue.js, the real trouble is processing the queue asynchronously every time a request completes. Or more like everytime there is an available http channel that has been freed we need to take the highest priority item.

Comment: Do not make any benchmarks by yourself, your evaluation may be flawed. Use [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/) which is doing really good acquisition of benchmark data.

Comment: Are you referring to my stats printed at the end? Those are not benchmarks as I am not comparing different implementations really. I just wanted to know how long it takes. Also I do not see how my evaluation might be flawed, and if so, so what? A framework here will just over complicate things, I rather keep it simple. Nonetheless, it looks like a cool framework :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you heard "priority queue", you should think about having a heap data structure.  They are not the only way to do that, but they are simple to implement and so are a good first goto.

See http://eloquentjavascript.net/appendix2.html for a random implementation.  They assume that when you create the heap, you pass in a function that takes an element and returns its priority.  In your case you could store elements like `[priority, object]` and initialize your heap wth a function like `function (x) {return x[0]}`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment btilly :). I actually found an even simpler PriorityQueue implementation using and sorting an array at: https://github.com/STRd6/PriorityQueue.js. However, my trouble is now more around the async nature of Node and how to process the queue asynchronously. I cannot just loop until the queue is empty, I need to somehow process the queue each time an item has been completed (i.e. a request has returned from the server). I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @yagudaev The question then is how to simulate a fixed pool of workers.  What you do is have a global count of available workers that starts off with a positive number.  And a `launchWorker` command that does nothing if that count is 0, and otherwise decrements the count and starts processing the queue asynchronously.  At the end of processing a queue item, increment that count.  And call `launchWorker` every time you enqueue an item.  Assuming no bugs in your code, that will cause up to a fixed number of items to be processed in parallel.

Comment: Yes I think so. Do you mean something like: http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2010/09/04/limiting-concurrency-node-js/ (the first approach sound very similar to what you are describing).

Comment: That is exactly the right idea.  Of course for a real application you'd want some logging added so that if some of the jobs got stuck, you could track it down...